# checking a pattern present in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

How to check if a url or url pattern is presnt or not in a string using javascript.

```
<script language="javascript">
var str="http://localhost/testprj?test=123213123";
var s=location.href;
if(s.match('/http://localhost/testprj?test=1232/'){
    alert('welcome!!');
}
</script>
```

what i need is to check the url pattern.

complete code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
<style>
.active{
    color:#009900;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

    <div id="menu">
    <ul><li>
    <ul><li>    <a href="html1.html">0</a>
        <a href="html.html" >1</a>
        <a href="2">2</a>
        </li>
    </ul></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">

        var c=document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a').length;
        var v=document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a');
        var s=location.href;
        //alert(s.match('html'));
        for(var i=0;i<c;i++){
            //alert('href'+v[i].className);
            if(v[i].href==location.href){
                v[i].className='active';
            }

        }

    </script>   


    </body>
</html>
```

this is working fine , but if the get params are cause some problms...

**like page.php?page=userlist**
works fine

but

**like page.php?page=userlist&id=121221**

this is the base link url
***link***

Comment: In the complete code, I don't see any URL regex (along the lines of what we have been suggesting).  However, if I understand "get params are cause some problms" right, you may need to do some server-side (PHP) escaping of the regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes finaly i got the solution
i used the functions

```
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(strstr(url,a[i].href)) {
            a[i].className='active';
        }
    }

    function strstr( url, href) {
        var pos = 0;
        url += '';
        pos = url.indexOf( href );
        if (pos == -1) {
            return false;
        } 
        else{
            if(strcmp(url,href)==0)
               return 1;
       }

    }
    function strcmp ( str1, str2 ) {
       return ( ( str1 == str2 ) ? 0 : ( ( str1 > str2 ) ? 1 : -1 ) );
    }
```

like this way, its working fine!!!

Thank you

Comment: Althoug it looks ok, the use of regular expressions is the correct answer to the question "checking a pattern present in a string using javascript" since this function only can check for substrings occurring in the url. For the specific case of substring checking a good question and answer has already been posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring

Answer (score 4):

For pattern checking, you will want to look into [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions).

What particular pattern do you want to check for? If you just want to check whether a string is a URL, the following code should do:

```
var myString = "http://blah.com/helloworld/";
if (myString.match(/http:\/\//)) {
    alert("'myString' is a URL.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/http:\/\/localhost\/testprj\?test=1232/.test(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just had some minor syntax issues:

```
var re = /http:\/\/localhost\/testprj\?test=1232/
var s=location.href;
if(s.match(re)) { 
  alert('welcome!!'); 
}
```

Comment: /http:\/\/localhost\/testprj\?test=1232/


i cant use like this. because , please check my Question i will update

Answer (score 0):

note that regular expressions are a data type of their own in javascript: no quotes or anything, just `/` delimeters