# How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, string-matching

Usually I would expect a `String.contains()` method, but there doesn't seem to be one.

What is a reasonable way to check for this?

Answer (score 15857, accepted):

ECMAScript 6  introduced [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const string = "foo";
const substring = "oo";

console.log(string.includes(substring)); // true
```

`String.prototype.includes` is **case-sensitive** and [is **not** supported by Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-string-includes) without a [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.string.includes.js).

In ECMAScript 5 or older environments, use [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), which returns -1 when a substring cannot be found:

```js
var string = "foo";
var substring = "oo";

console.log(string.indexOf(substring) !== -1); // true
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, and the OP never requested for a "case-sensitive" search, it should be noted that `includes` performs a [case-sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) search.

Comment: @Aashiq: Yes, an empty string is a substring of every string.

Comment: @Gavin by default if I want to know if something is a substring, I imagine it would be case-sensitive. After all, "A" and "a" are different characters. The OP never requested a "case-insensitive" search ( which is a trivial solution, if you make everything lowercase)

Comment: `indexOf` is also case case-sensitive search, so both `includes` and `indexOf` are case-sensitive .

Comment: Why is a discussion of case sensitivity even taking place here?

Comment: what is the complexity of javascript implementation of string.indexOf()?

Comment: In 'C' a string is just an array of char. Is there a solution for strstr on an array of any type of object? Let's say of a specific type, as in Uint8Array?

Comment: @MaxWaterman: Nothing built-in. Options include converting to a string (`String.fromCharCode(...array).includes(String.fromCharCode(...subarray))`) or implementing a string search algorithm for arrays (e.g. KMP as seen in another answer here).

Comment: @Ry- Shame. I know about solutions in JavaScript, but they all (seem to) involve copying the array or implementing a search JS-side, which is what we're trying to avoid. It seems like a curious omission :/

Comment: the funnys thing about `.includes()`;  Previously it name was `.contains()` like `C#`,  it name was proposed for many years and maybe since javascript born, but people with high authority in JS hate so much MSoft so it renamed to `includes`

Comment: @uingtea: [wrong](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible)

Comment: @KWallace a significant amount of freshly hatched newblet developers are coming from a case-insensitive-by-default world. It's overwhelmingly and increasingly common in higher-level UI/UX to do things case-insensitive by default. To you and me and the rest of us lost-in-the-sauce fluent-in-programming nerds, it's so obvious that case sensitivity is expected that "is this a substring of that?" automatically implies an assumption of case sensitivity without a conscious question/thought that it could be otherwise, but to anyone who hasn't yet learned to expect that, it really is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 792):

[There is a `String.prototype.includes` in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
"potato".includes("to");
> true
```

Note that this [does not work in Internet Explorer or some other old browsers](https://caniuse.com/?v=1#feat=es6-string-includes) with no or incomplete ES6 support. To make it work in old browsers, you may wish to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), a shim library like [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim), or this [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill):

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof start !== 'number') {
      start = 0;
    }

    if (start + search.length > this.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: just curious, why do you need to check the length? Does IE fail in that case or something?

Comment: Also the checking for `number` fails to perform like `includes`. Example: es6 includes returns false for `"abc".includes("ab", "1")` this polyfill will return true

Answer (score 107):

Another alternative is [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) (Knuth–Morris–Pratt).

The KMP algorithm searches for a length-*m* substring in a length-*n* string in worst-case O(*n*+*m*) time, compared to a worst-case of O(*n*⋅*m*) for the naive algorithm, so using KMP may be reasonable if you care about worst-case time complexity.

Here's a JavaScript implementation by Project Nayuki, taken from https://www.nayuki.io/res/knuth-morris-pratt-string-matching/kmp-string-matcher.js:

```
// Searches for the given pattern string in the given text string using the Knuth-Morris-Pratt string matching algorithm.
// If the pattern is found, this returns the index of the start of the earliest match in 'text'. Otherwise -1 is returned.
```

```js
function kmpSearch(pattern, text) {
  if (pattern.length == 0)
    return 0; // Immediate match

  // Compute longest suffix-prefix table
  var lsp = [0]; // Base case
  for (var i = 1; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    var j = lsp[i - 1]; // Start by assuming we're extending the previous LSP
    while (j > 0 && pattern[i] !== pattern[j])
      j = lsp[j - 1];
    if (pattern[i] === pattern[j])
      j++;
    lsp.push(j);
  }

  // Walk through text string
  var j = 0; // Number of chars matched in pattern
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    while (j > 0 && text[i] != pattern[j])
      j = lsp[j - 1]; // Fall back in the pattern
    if (text[i]  == pattern[j]) {
      j++; // Next char matched, increment position
      if (j == pattern.length)
        return i - (j - 1);
    }
  }
  return -1; // Not found
}

console.log(kmpSearch('ays', 'haystack') != -1) // true
console.log(kmpSearch('asdf', 'haystack') != -1) // false
```

Comment: Not questioning anything on this approach... but why implementing KMP where there's a `includes` or `indexOf` on the table. (Although the underneath impl of those maybe using KMP... not sure)

Comment: KMP provides linear O(n) performance here.

Comment: @wz366 KMP provides O(n), what about the rest? Any Idea?

Comment: If this is used for speed, it would likely run faster if you replaced `.charAt(i)` with `[i]` to avoid the extra function calls.

Comment: 99% of the times, doing this is overkill and harmful for non-computational aspects of a software project. Unless you're working on something extremely critical, I strongly advise against following this path... I don't think that big players like Twitter, Facebook, or most of Google products would even use this... so why should you?

Comment: @ClintEastwood: This same approach works on things that aren’t JavaScript strings, which can be useful in all sorts of applications. (You should probably import it from a package if you need it, though, instead of embedding a copy from a Stack Overflow answer.) “Extremely critical” isn’t the right distinction.